# PSObject with relational values - one to manny

Tags: powershell, psobject

want to populate the following PSObject so it can have a one:one or one:many relationship between IPs and hostnames.

```
$hostobj = New-Object PSOBject
$hostobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ip_address" -Value ""
$hostobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "hostnames" -Value ""
```

This gives me the correct headings but when I try add more than one value, it will error one trying to add the repeat values:

```
$hostobj = New-Object PSOBject
$hostobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ip_address" -Value "1.1.1.1"
$hostobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "hostnames" -Value "server1"
$hostobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ip_address" -Value "2.2.2.2"
$hostobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "hostnames" -Value "server2"
```

Why is this?

Can do the one to many bit fairly easily:

```
$hostobj = New-Object PSOBject
$hostobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ip_address" -Value "1.1.1.1"
$hostobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "hostnames" -Value "server1", "server2", "server3"
```

Either of these is the data set to extra from:

```
1.1.1.1     server1     
2.2.2.2     server2
3.3.3.3     server3
4.5.6.7     server4     server5     server6     server7     
8.8.8.8     server8     
9.9.9.9     server9

1.1.1.1
server1
2.2.2.2
server2
3.3.3.3
server3
4.5.6.7
server4
server5
server6
server7
8.8.8.8
server8
9.9.9.9
server9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to create a list of objects like:

```
$ArrayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$hostobj = New-Object PSOBject
$hostobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ip_address" -Value "1.1.1.1"
$hostobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "hostnames" -Value "server1"

$ArrayList.Add($hostobj)

$hostobj = New-Object PSOBject
$hostobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ip_address" -Value "2.2.2.2"
$hostobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "hostnames" -Value "server2"

$ArrayList.Add($hostobj)
```

so that `$ArrayList` contains all the host objects. and each object has one value for `ip_address` and `hostnames`.

If this does not help you please specify what you expect/what exactly you are trying to do/work with.

Comment: Thanks, so this is an array list containing multiple PSObjects, correct?

Comment: you can do this in a much shorter format: `[System.Collections.ArrayList]$ArrayList = @( [PSCustomObject]@{ ip_address = "1.1.1.1"; hostnames = "server1" }, [PSCustomObject]@{ ip_address = "2.2.2.2"; hostnames = "server2" } )`